# Keep value in html input box below set amount

Tags: javascript, validation

I have in input box that can only contain numerical values (with use of [this](http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/) plugin).
Now I want the input to be below, say 90.
If a value is entered that exceeds this max cap or cannot be parsed, the previous value should be inserted.
By default, the box will contain "1".

```
<input id="targetQuantity" name="targetQuantity" type="text" value="1" />
```

I imagine I should catch the current value somehow. Try to parse the new value. If it is an allowed value, continue with this value, if not, put the old one back.
As my JS skills are really limited I don't even know what events are available to me and I find the documentation I found on the intarwebz rather confusing.

--EDIT--
I ended up using [Sergei's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630129/keep-value-in-html-input-box-below-set-amount/630228#630228) code and using [Aaron's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630129/keep-value-in-html-input-box-below-set-amount/630192#630192) usability advice.
All I'm looking for now is to enable/disable a whole form's submit.
Just disabling a submit button is not enough.

Comment: Why do this with javascript?  Why not just add maxlength="90" to the input element's attributes?

Comment: because maxlength allows 90 characters. he wants maxvalue, if it existed...

Comment: Duh! Should have read that more carefully...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input id="targetQuantity" name="targetQuantity" type="text" value="1" onkeyup="check(this)" />
```

...
JavaScript:

```
var v=1;

function check(i) {      
  if(i.value > 100) {
    i.value=v;
    alert("< 100");
  }
  else
    v=i.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help: [JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Now a word on usability: Never ever change the value as the user types. If you want to know why, try it.

Instead, turn the field red (set the background color). When the form is submitted, run the validation again to make sure the user has fixed the mistake. If not, display an *inline* error message ("value must be < 90") somewhere near the field and set the focus to the field.

**Do not use alert()**. alert() is for debugging only and has no use in a real web application since it a) interrupts the work flow of the user and b) doesn't work when the user is typing: Eventually, the user will hit space and the dialog will close, possibly with the user ever noticing that there was a dialog or what it said.

You may want to check out a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) because they already contain all the building blocks you need and they fix a lot of the browser bugs for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't use alerts except for debugging. In fact, they are the reason why I surf without script in Opera most of the time. Also, I'm already using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

write this js in a javascript code block:

```
var LastGood = 1;
function CheckValue(input, max) {
    var value = Number(input.value);
    if (NaN == value || input.value>max) { //it is not a number or is too big - revert
        input.value = LastGood;
    } else { //it is ok, save it as the last good value
        LastGood = value;
    }
}
```

change your input form to

```
<input id="targetQuantity" name="targetQuantity" type="text" value="1" onkeyup="CheckValue(this, 90)" />
```